# Como realizo un UPDATE con un SELECT del campo y las filas que necesito Actualizar?

Tags: postgresql

Necesito Actualizar 21 filas de un cierto campo, pero para llegar a estos 21 filas tengo que realizar un `select` e `inner join` con otra tabla, como puede realizar el `UPDATE` a esta 21 filas.

Este es el `SELECT` que utilizo para sacar los datos.

```
SELECT clave_cpi
  FROM catcpi_alumnos A
 INNER JOIN catcpi ID
    ON A.idcpi = ID.idcpi
 WHERE TRIM(gpogeneracional) = '16MSP-DURANGO'
```

Comment: Por favor, agrega detalles concretos a la pregunta para poder ayudarte: estructura y ejemplo de datos de tus tablas, el resultado deseado, lo que has intentado hasta ahora, etc.

Comment: tienes el select que te trae las 21 filas?

Comment: Ok, este es el SELECT que utilizo para sacar los datos.              SELECT clave_cpi 
   FROM catcpi_alumnos A
     INNER JOIN catcpi ID
        ON A.idcpi = ID.idcpi
WHERE TRIM(gpogeneracional) = '16MSP-DURANGO'                                          Ahora lo que quiero es actualizar los campos de la consulta por ejemplo 'MZT2016112 ' a todos estos les quiero es cambiar MZT por DGO. con la funcion replace() de postgres.    Soy nuevo en el Foro...

Comment: Y cual es la tabla que quieres actualizar?

Comment: La tabla 'catcpi', el campo 'clave_cpi'

Comment: ¿Cuales son las claves primarias de ambas tablas? ¿A qué tabla pertenece el campo gpogeneracional? Me imagino que es catcpi_alumnos, pero para estar seguro. Nuevamente, lo ideal sería que describas bien la estructura de tus tablas por medio de editar tu pregunta. Por favor, ponte en nuestro lugar... no tenemos el contexto que tu tienes, así que tienes que ayudarnos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes intentar hacer un subquery

```
UPDATE dummy
SET customer=subquery.customer,
    address=subquery.address,
    partn=subquery.partn
FROM (SELECT address_id, customer, address, partn
      FROM  /* big hairy SQL */ ...) AS subquery
WHERE dummy.address_id=subquery.address_id;
```

Algo así

```
UPDATE catcpi
SET catcpi.clave_cpi=subquery.clave_cpi
FROM (
    SELECT clave_cpi , A.idcpi
    FROM catcpi_alumnos A 
    INNER JOIN catcpi ID ON A.idcpi = ID.idcpi 
    WHERE TRIM(gpogeneracional) = '16MSP-DURANGO') AS subquery
WHERE catcpi.idcpi=subquery.idcpi;
```

Comment: ERROR:  column "catcpi" of relation "catcpi" does not exist
LINE 2: SET catcpi=subquery.clave_cpi
            ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "catcpi" of relation "catcpi" does not exist
SQL state: 42703

Comment: si, le faltaba el campo a actualizar `SET catcpi.clave_cpi=subquery.clave_cpi`

Comment: UPDATE catcpi
SET clave_cpi = replace ((subquery.clave_cpi), 'MZT', 'DGO')
FROM (
    SELECT ID.idcpi, clave_cpi
    FROM catcpi_alumnos A 
    INNER JOIN catcpi ID ON A.idcpi = ID.idcpi 
    WHERE TRIM(gpogeneracional) = '16MSP-DURANGO') AS subquery
WHERE catcpi.idcpi=subquery.idcpi

Comment: MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS, ASI QUEDO RESUELTO MI PROBLEMA, ME SIRVIO BASTANTE TU AYUDA !!!

Comment: Cierto, me falto el replace, bueno pero ese fue el menor de los males.